# Keeping a row with the max value in a group in Orange

Tags: python, python-3.x, orange

I have a dataset with numeric scores and several group criteria e.g. Class, Test, Score. How can I select only the top score from each class and test to pass to the next widget? An example of the unprocessed data is below:

> Class  Test      Score
>  
>   A      English   99 
>   A      English   108 
>   A      English   30 
>   A      Geography 20 
>   A      Geography 34 
>   A      Geography 101 
>   B      Science   90 
>   B      Science   30

What I want to pass to the next widget is the max score from each group, as below

> Class  Test      Score 
>   A      English   108 
>   A      Geography 101 
>   B      Science   90

I know how I could do this in SQL, but the SQL Widget will not install and I've slightly lost the will to live after 2 hours of trying to get psycopg2 installed and failing. Is there any other way aside from SQL that this can be done within Orange?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand your question exactly. Can you better describe your data? What are columns in the Table and what exactly do you want to make with what column?

Comment: Hi - I've updated the question. Thanks so much for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no widget to which will do that directly but you can use the `Python Script` widget. You can connect your input at widgets input and then paste code similar to this in the widget:

```
from Orange.data import Table, Domain, DiscreteVariable, ContinuousVariable
import pandas as pd

# transforming table to pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(in_data.X, columns=list(map(str, in_data.domain.attributes)))

# here we use pandas to find lines with maximal scores in a group
idx = df.groupby(['Test'])['Score'].transform(max) == df['Score']

# transform results back to Onange Table
out_data = Table(Domain(in_data.domain.attributes), df[idx].values)
```

Data that you connect to the widget are available in the `in_data` variable and you must save your output data in `out_data` variable. Here we used pandas to find maximal rows in the group since it is simpler. You can also use a standard Pythonic way.

Now you connect the output of the `Python Script` widget to your widget you want to use.

Comment: THanks so much for your reply. I think I'm almost there. The following bit of code: 
**out_data = Table(a.domain, df[idx].values)**

produces the following error though -

**NameError: name 'a' is not defined**. Should this value be something else? I've tried a few options. Using in_data instead kicks up a fuss about _"ValueError: Invalid number of meta attribute columns (0 != 3)"_ as 3 of my columns are meta attributes, but I need these! Apologies for all the questions, I'm new to Orange, Python AND pandas!

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. I tested the following code with different variables and forgot to replace a. It must be `in_data`.